# How to display elements, refering to the selected radio button ? using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

**What I try to achieve:**
I'm working on a code, which does fetch categories together with other elements from a database (php & mysql).
These elements/nodes are all in a "`<label> ... </label>`" for a radio button.
If a user clicks on one of these labels for a radio button, the category name and an img, which are also in the label, should how up ALSO in a other "`<div id="selection"> ... </div>`".

**What does work:**
By clicking on a radiobutton/label, I already can fetch the radioButton value (in my case the value must be the the category id).

**What doesn't work:**
I cant fetch the other elements in this label and display it ALSO in a other span

**VERY IMPORTANT!: The content in the labels getting fetched from a database, so it is dynamically!**

Here is a simple version of my code without php elements, but the output should be kinda the same.

```js
function check() {
  var radioBttn = document.querySelectorAll("input[name = 'pet']");
  var countRadioBttn = radioBttn.length;

  for (i = 0; i < countRadioBttn; i++) {
    if (radioBttn[i].checked) {
      selection.innerHTML = "You selected a/n " + radioBttn[i].value + ",<br>good choice!";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;font-family: arial; font-family: ubuntu; -webkit-touch-callout: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;}
b{color: dodgerBlue;}
body{background-color: rgba(50,50,50);}
#option{width: 250px; height: 100px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3); margin: 10px; padding: 10px; color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);}
#selection{width: 250px; height: 55px; background-color: rgba(100,100,100,.3); margin: 10px; padding: 10px; color: lightgreen;}
```

```html
<div id="option">
  <b>Option Box</b>
  <br>

  <label>
        <input onclick="check()" type="radio" name="pet" class="rb_category" value="id:1">
        <span>Cat</span>
        <img src=""></img>
    </label>

  <br>

  <label>
        <input onclick="check()" type="radio" name="pet" class="rb_category" value="id:2">
        <span>Dog</span>
        <img src=""></img>
    </label>

  <br>

  <label>
        <input onclick="check()" type="radio" name="pet" class="rb_category" value="id:3">
        <span>Hamster</span>
        <img src=""></img>
    </label>

  <br>

  <label>
        <input onclick="check()" type="radio" name="pet" class="rb_category" value="id:4">
        <span>Mammoth</span>
        <img src=""></img>
    </label>
</div>

<div id="selection">
  No selection yet
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```js
var rads = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=pet]");
for (var i = 0; i < rads.length; i++) {
  rads[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var parentLabel = this.closest("label");
    document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML =
      "You selected a/n " + this.value + ",<br>good choice!" +
      "<span>" + parentLabel.querySelector("span").innerHTML + "</span>" +
      "<img src='" + parentLabel.querySelector("img").src + "'/>";
  });
};
```

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;font-family: arial; font-family: ubuntu; -webkit-touch-callout: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none; user-select: none;}
b{color: dodgerBlue;}
body{background-color: rgba(50,50,50);}
#option{width: 250px; height: 100px; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3); margin: 10px; padding: 10px; color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);}
#selection{ width: 250px; height: 55px; background-color: rgba(100,100,100,.3); margin: 10px; padding: 10px; color: lightgreen;}
label>img { height:25% }
```

```html
<div id="option">
  <b>Option Box</b>
  <br>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="pet" class="rb_category" value="id:1">
        <span>Cat</span>
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-200-200-5.jpg" />
    </label>
  <br>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="pet" class="rb_category" value="id:2">
        <span>Dog</span>
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-8.jpg" />
    </label>
  <br>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="pet" class="rb_category" value="id:3">
        <span>Rhino</span>
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-1.jpg" />
    </label>

  <br>
  <label>
        <input type="radio" name="pet" class="rb_category" value="id:4">
        <span>Tiger</span>
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-200-200-3.jpg" />
    </label>
</div>
<br style="clear:both" />

<div id="selection">
  No selection yet
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Exactly how I need it !

Comment: Do note that “closest” is fairly new outside jQuery

Comment: So it is only compatible with newer browsers? A other little question: If I want to highlight the span in the option list, of the actual selected radio, I tried this in the js code: parentLabel.querySelector("span").style.color = "darkorange"; but then every span which I click, gets this color then and not only the actual selected radio button (I'm a js newbie)

Comment: I’ll look tomorrow